# Android WifiManager not enabling/disabling WiFi state

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifimanager

I have a mobile application that allows users to enable/disable WiFi on click of a button.

However I noticed today that my app is no longer able to change the WiFi status. It was working since before few weeks. I tried to debug it but the following method always returns false.

```
boolean result = wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
```

I am testing it on Samsung Galaxy Note 9 and Android 10.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This API is [no longer supported](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager#setWifiEnabled(boolean)) when targeting Android 10 or higher.

> Starting with Build.VERSION_CODES#Q, applications are not allowed to enable/disable Wi-Fi. Compatibility Note: For applications targeting Build.VERSION_CODES.Q or above, this API will always fail and return false. If apps are targeting an older SDK (Build.VERSION_CODES.P or below), they can continue to use this API.

Instead, you should use the [Settings.Panel](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Panel) API to present a system UI allowing users to enable or disable Wi-Fi.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
  startActivity(Intent(Settings.Panel.ACTION_INTERNET_CONNECTIVITY))
}
```

Comment: Actually my app used to enable/disable WiFi connection programmatically. I would like to do the same way if I can...

Comment: It's no longer possible. If you're targeting Android 10 (which is [required](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9859152?visit_id=637591338476399641-3263115555&rd=1#targetsdk&zippy=%2Ctarget-api-level-requirements-for-play-console) as of August 2020) that ability is now restricted.

Comment: Ohh my... is there any way on the Play store I can show my app to only those users who are under Android 10? The app should not be visible to them of they are Android 10 or above.....

Comment: You can technically specify a [maxSdkVersion](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element#max) in your manifest, but I would strongly recommend against it. If your users get an OS update to Android 10, your application will simply disappear. You would still need to set your SDK target to Android 10 to upload to the Play Store. 

Unless this is critical to your app functionality, you could alternatively consider just guarding that particular feature behind an SDK level check (i.e. `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) showWifiToggle()`)

Comment: Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Please note, this function is pretty broken if performed from a lock screen notification, for example if you added a notification button to turn on wifi. Tapping it does nothing and won't request unlock nor show the panel...